# Is there any flex video player which can play video byteArray stream?

Tags: video, air, flex4, video-streaming, video-processing

Is there any flex video player which play video byteArray stream? I want to play video file byteArray in video player.

Any web link or commercial component link or article would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check this, this might help you

```
private function playBytes(bytes:ByteArray):void 
{
            // detecting it's header
            if (bytes.readUTFBytes(3) != "FLV")
            {
                _text.appendText("\nFile \""+ file +"\" is not a FLV")
                return void;
            }

            bytes.position = 0;
            netConnection.connect(null);
            netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
            netStream.client = { onMetaData:function(obj:Object):void { } }
            video.attachNetStream(netStream);

            addChild(video); 


            // put the NetStream class into Data Generation mode
            netStream.play(null);
            // before appending new bytes, reset the position to the beginning
            netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            // append the FLV video bytes
            netStream.appendBytes(bytes);
}
```

this property/method is not available in 3.0 or 3.5 sdk

```
netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
netStream.appendBytes(bytes);
```

you can use playerglobal.swc from 4.1 sdk and above, it 'll work...